# what is the code for checking if the user press yes\no\cancel ? (c#)

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

i'm using messageBoxButton.YesNoCancel button, and i wanna know which button the user press

how do i do it ?

this is the code:

```
 MessageBox.Show("this item is already in the system, do you want to add it anyway ?",
                 "Question",MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
```

thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store the answers in a [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx) object. Then you can analyze the answers like that:

```
       DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("this item is already in the system, do you want to add it anyway ?", "Question",MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);

       if (result == DialogResult.Yes) {
           //your code here
       } else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel) {
           //your code here
       } else if (result == DialogResult.No) {
          // your code here
       }
```

Answer (score 5):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x49kd7z.aspx:

```
        result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons);
        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            // Closes the parent form.
            this.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("your question?", 
                      "window title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
switch(dialogResult){
   case DialogResult.Yes: break;
   case DialogResult.No: break;
}
```

All possible dialog results:

- DialogResult.Yes
- DialogResult.No
- DialogResult.Cancel
- DialogResult.Abort
- DialogResult.Ignore
- DialogResult.None
- DialogResult.Retry
- DialogResult.OK

And see the [MessageBox MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx) entry.

Answer (score 2):

The [`MessageBox.Show` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show.aspx) returns a value of type [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx) that indicates which button the user clicked. By examining that return value, you can figure out which one they chose.

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("this item is already in the system, do you want to add it anyway ?", "Question",MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);

if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    // they clicked Yes
}
else if (result == DialogResult.No)
{
    // they clicked No
}
else
{
    // they clicked Cancel
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a `switch` statement, rather than `if`.

Answer (score 0):

MessageBox.Show() returns a DialogResult.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x49kd7z.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx

```
result = MessageBox.Show(...);

if(result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes) // or No or Cancel
        {

        }
```